# The explicit transaction has been forcibly cancelled. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8032000F)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, monogame

I am developing a WP8 MonoGame app. I added the app to Windows Apphub and created 4 in app consumbalbe products. 2 weeks ago I tested my IAP retrieval and purchasing code in the emulator since testing is not allowed on device. All went well then. Today I returned back to finishing my app and noticed that retrieving products no longer works. The following code raises an exception now:

```
ListingInformation listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

The exception is

> The explicit transaction has been forcibly cancelled. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8032000F)

I did make sure that my App ID and Publisher ID matches those in my store listing. I am very confused since this code has been working perfectly fine for a while now and then it suddenly doesn't without any code change.

**UPDATE**: I narrowed down the issue a bit. I replaced my App ID with the ID of another live app and now I can retrieve and view the IAP products, so the problem is not with the code it seems. A little more detail about the current app am developing. When uploading an alpha version of it 2 months ago, I accidentally forgot to set publishing to manual so it got published automatically 2 days later. Soon after I discovered my mistake and made it hidden from the app store. Since this does not seem to be a problem from my end, maybe IAP products expire after 2 months of inactivity?

Comment: I think CurrentAppSimulator Class is used in Windows Store app it's not working in Windows Phone-8 App.

Comment: CurrentAppSimulator class is not available in WP8 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem by suspecting an issue which I have least predicted to be the cause. My app was set as hidden from the market, but the IAP continued to appear for testing long after that until a few days ago this issue happened. After trying everything, I speculated that the IAP have also suddenly gone hidden with the app, so I published it today and soon after all the IAP returned and now load correctly, no exception anymore. Weird issue but solved!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just hided my app, but IAPs still available. Guess that's the cause for all the exceptions that pop up now!